# How can I show that the small change in an area of a circular segment is equal to $\frac12r^2(1-\cos\theta)\,\delta \theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

The question specifies that the shaded segment has area of $A\text{ cm}^2$. The first part of the question also verifies that $$A = \frac{1}2 r^2 (\theta-sin\theta)$$

However the second part of the question states that when the angle POQ is increased to $(\theta + \delta\theta)$ radians, where $\delta\theta$ is small, the area of the shaded segment is increased to $(A + \delta A) cm^2$, where $\delta A$ is small.

The questions afterwards asks to show that $$\delta A = \frac{1}2 r^2 (1-\cos\theta)\delta \theta$$

And this is what I am failing to match in any way. I understand how to begin and have proceeded with multiple steps in multiple approaches in an attempt to get to this exact expression,  but can't understand how to get there in any of my approaches. I'll share my last approach that I thought got pretty close down below.

$$ A+\delta A = \frac{1}2 r^2 ( \theta + \delta \theta - \sin⁡(\theta + \delta \theta)) $$

Using the given expression for A, ${A = \frac{1}2 r^2 (\theta-\sin\theta)}$, to use as substitution here, and expanding the expression from within the parentheses, I get:

$$\begin{align}
\delta A &= \frac{1}2 r^2 \theta + \frac{1}2 r^2 \delta \theta - \frac{1}2 r^2  \sin⁡(\theta + \delta \theta ) - \frac{1}2 r^2 (\theta - \sin⁡ \theta ) \\[4pt]
\implies\quad \delta A &= \frac{1}2 r^2 \delta \theta - \frac{1}2 r^2  \sin⁡(\theta + \delta \theta ) +  \frac{1}2 r^2 \sin⁡ \theta \\[4pt]
\implies\quad \delta A &= \frac{1}2 r^2 \delta \theta - \frac{1}2 r^2 \times 2 \cos(\frac{\theta+\theta+\delta \theta}2) \sin (\frac{\theta - \theta - \delta \theta}2) \\[4pt]
\implies\quad \delta A &= \frac{1}2 r^2 \delta \theta - r^2  \cos(\frac{2\theta+\delta \theta}2) \sin (\frac{- \delta \theta}2) 
\end{align}$$

I have tried to use $ cos \alpha sin \beta $ formula to proceed to only reach another dead-end. I also tried using $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ formula instead of $\sin \alpha + \sin \beta $ for $ \sin(\theta + \delta \theta) $ and still reached another dead-end.

I can feel that I'm missing something super simple here. But, after 3 hours of racking my brain to find nothing regarding the solution to this, I have come online to seek for aid from a proper math community!

This is my first post here by the way, so forgive me if I made any mistakes. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Taylor's expansion around $\theta$.

$A(\theta) = {r^2 \over 2}(\theta - \sin\theta)$

$A(\theta + \delta_\theta) = A(\theta) + A'(\theta)\delta_\theta$

$A'(\theta) = {\partial \over \partial \theta} A(\theta) = {r^2 \over 2}(1- \cos\theta)$

This gives:

$A(\theta + \delta_\theta) = A(\theta) + {r^2 \over 2}(1- \cos\theta)\delta_\theta$

Your first principle approach is also good:

$\sin(\theta + \delta_\theta) = \sin\theta \cos \delta_\theta + \cos \theta \sin \delta_\theta$ (trigonometric identity)

Now use, for small $\delta_\theta$:

$\cos \delta_\theta \approx 1$

$\sin \delta_\theta \approx \delta_\theta$

These approximations are based on Taylor series expansions of $\sin$ and $\cos$. If you plug in the above approximations, you will get the desired result.